# getting broken image in React App

Tags: reactjs, image

I am trying to access an image in a React App.  When I run the code I get a broken image icon on web page.  I am not sure if I am accessing the right path for the image.  The code I have is the following:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class HeaderName extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>The AquaStars New Website.</h1>
                <img src="./images/picture_swimmers.png" />
            </div>
            )
        }
}

export default HeaderName;
```

The structure of the code is the following[image]

Comment: try to remove "." from `src` attribute. Also if you are using `create-react-app` or something like that you should import image directly as rest of your resources to generate path automatically. LIke `import Image from '<path>'` and then put `Image` in src

Comment: React just puts HTML on the page. Where assets live is up to you and your webserver. If you're using webpack you're supposed to require() the path to the image. Suggested reading: https://blog.andrewray.me/webpack-when-to-use-and-why/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you are using the wrong path. If I am seeing this correct the code you posted above is from header.js which is in the src folder. Since your images folder is in public you would need to step up one folder then over to public first. The path you would want to use is,

```
    ../public/images/picture_swimmers.png
```

Just note if you plan on creating a production build this path would be different. One suggestion I have used before is if the images must be in the public folder then you can reference them like,

```
    src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/images/picture_swimmers.png'}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue today, my image appeared broken.

When I imported the image first in the component it worked fine, in your case it will look something like the code below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import image from './images/picture_swimmers.png'    
    
class HeaderName extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>The AquaStars New Website.</h1>
                <img src={image} />
            </div>
            )
        }
    }
    
   export default HeaderName;
```

Comment: this is not allowed if your image is outside the source folder

Comment: Yes, but you can create a folder for images inside src folder

Comment: purely as a point of interest: does that comply with React best practices?