# How to make a Dynamic dropdown done in React with SQL database

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I'm building a react app using facebook's:
https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

I´m new to react and I havent done a dropdown menu before. I have read a lot in the web and I figure I maybe need to use the select and options tags?

I want to have 4 image buttons as I call Main menu (three of the buttons will be able to navigate directly to the picked page).
The last image button will show an undermenu with 12 options pages to go to.

Option Option Option Option
     Undermenu
     12 options

I´m unsure where I shall begin, right now I have done some coding before I knew I needed to connect it to the SQL database.

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './sass/style.scss';
import Admin from "./components/routes/Admin";
import DropdownMenu from "./components/DropdownMenu";




class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">


        <Admin />

        <DropdownMenu />

        <p className="TEST"> lorem imsum </p>
      </div>


    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

DropdownMenu.js component:

```
import React from 'react';

import main_menu_home from '../images/Buttons/main_menu_home.png';
import main_menu_dragons from '../images/Buttons/main_menu_dragons.png';
import main_menu_dragon_test from '../images/Buttons/main_menu_dragon_test.png';
import main_menu_fortune_cookie from '../images/Buttons/main_menu_fortune_cookie.png';



const DropdownMenu = props => (
<header>
    <nav>

      <div className="dragonMenu-container">

       <div className="dragonMenu">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <img
                id="Home"
                className="Main_home"
                src={main_menu_home}
                alt="Home_button_image"
                />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img
                    id="Dragons"
                    className="Main_Dragons"
                    src={main_menu_dragons}
                    alt="Dragons_button_image"
                  />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img
                    id="Dragon_test"
                    className="Main_Dragon_test"
                    src={main_menu_dragon_test}
                    alt="Dragon_test_button_image"
                  />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img
                    id="Fortune_cookie"
                    className="Main_fortune_cookie"
                    src={main_menu_fortune_cookie}
                    alt="Fortune_cookie_button_image"
                  />
            </li>
     </ul>
    </div> 

    </div>


    </nav>

</header>
);

export default DropdownMenu;
```

Here the code just display four images which it gets from the images/Buttons folder. Maybe you don´t need so many imports and can get all the images with just a proper link to the image but I donno how to.
I think I need a global variable that pointing where all my images are so I can just have to invoke said variable to access the folder where the pictures are. 
Ideas?

But back to the Dropdown problem:

I guess I need to create a table in my Sql? 
But I donno how.

My problem is that I think of all things at the same time I need to do, but can´t easy myself to do one thing at the time.

I have more code for when I before fetched all from another table if you want to see that code as well.

Any questions, feel free to ask away :)

// Dragoness

UPDATED 18 sep 2019:

Right now, I have come this far:
I can now talk to the SQL database with react and print out some data from the SQL database itself. My problem now is that I just see broken images, does anyone have a solution for my problem?

[What I see on the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxJNQ.png)

[My SQL database menus table with 4 columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1XFH.png)

[What I wrote in the browse tag to enter my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQvGC.png)

[Where I have MainMenu.js file and where I want the Buttons images from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCMl5.png)

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './sass/style.scss';
import Admin from "./components/routes/Admin";
import DropdownMenu from "./components/DropdownMenu";
import MainMenu from "./components/MainMenu";




class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

         <Admin />

        <DropdownMenu />
         <MainMenu />

        <p className="TEST"> lorem imsum </p>
        <div><img src='./images/Buttons/main_menu_home.png'/> </div>
      </div>


    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

fetchMenu.php:

```
<?php
    /* This file fetches current menus . */
    include_once 'database.php';
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM menus ORDER BY picUrl ASC");
    $statement->execute();
    $data = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

MainMenu.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import "../App.scss";


    class DropDownMenu {
    id: 0;
    picUrl: "";
    linkUrl: "";
    isSubmenu: "";
}

class MainMenu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

      this.state = {
          allMenus: []
      }
  }

 fetchAllMenus = () => {
        fetch("http://localhost/dragonology/server/fetchMenu.php")
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            this.setState({ allMenus: data });

          });
      }



  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchAllMenus();

  }


  render() {

    let menu = this.state.allMenus.map((item) => {
        return (<div key={item.id}><img src={item.picUrl} alt="dropdownmenu_main_and_under"/> - {item.linkUrl} - {item.isSubmenu}</div>)
    });

        console.log(menu);



    return (
     <div>{menu}</div>
    );
  }
}


export default MainMenu;
```

Thank you in advance

// Dragoness

**Updated 19 sep 2019 with solution**

I got some tips from those links:

I changed my images folder to be in the public instead of in src:

[getting broken image in React App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51974767/getting-broken-image-in-react-app)

Started to see a pattern that most of the tables with an image inside have some kind of "name" column, at least it worked for me:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lTyks6s6b6E

All my success steps I took:

Fixed:
 1. I added a folder called images inside the public folder.
 2. Added one image of the main menu that I called home.
 3. Went to the SQL database, deleted the old rows I tried to display the 
     data from that you can see on the browse tab that was inside the table 
     menus.
 4. Added another column called picName. Took it as a varchar with 60 in 
     lengh.
 5. Changed the settings on the picUrl to be a varchar with the lengh of
     255 instead of 100 that I had before.
 6. I did a test using the insert tab selection to add a row with the image 
     link I had before with the dot dot slash and it worked!.
 7. Added 15 more rows(all main and undermenu buttons with its data).
 8. After that I changed the folder structure again to have images/Buttons 
     and added all the button images that I had inside the src folder before.
 9. Deleted all the images that were on the old folder.
 10. Fixed: App.js took away the import of the DropDownMenu.js component and that it didnt print out my DropDownMenu.js component anymore.

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './sass/style.scss';
import Admin from "./components/routes/Admin";
import MainMenu from "./components/MainMenu";




class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

         <Admin />

         <MainMenu />

        <p className="TEST"> lorem imsum </p>
        <div><img src='./images/Buttons/main_menu_home.png'/> </div>
      </div>


    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I couldn´t add the images of how my SQL database look now instead of before/where I find my images now in what folder because am new in Stack Overflow and don´t have enough reputation apperely. But those above are the steps I took to solve my problem :)

Comment: I updated my info in how long I have come for the moment now my problem is broken images, anyone have a solution for that?

Comment: Problem solved by myself ,see the steps how above, couldnt add the result images because I´m new on Stack Oveflow